# How to find Tensorflow Serving version?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

To find Tensorflow version we can do that by:
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.**version**)'

Tensorflow Serving is a separate install, so how to find the version of Tensorflow Serving?

Is it same as Tensorflow? Do not see any reference/comments or documentation related to this.

Answer (score 5):

After you have installed `tensorflow_model_server`, run this

```
tensorflow_model_server --version
```

you will get the version of tf-serving.
In my case, i get

```
TensorFlow ModelServer: 1.13.0-rc1+dev.sha.f16e777
TensorFlow Library: 1.13.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When building TF-Serving, you are going to do:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
cd serving`

From there, you can submit:
`git branch --list -a`

This will list all the possible TF-Serving versions. At the time of writing, I have:

> remotes/origin/master
>
> remotes/origin/r0.5.1

Then, you can checkout the branch you want before you build TF-Serving:
`git checkout r0.5.1`

Comment: How about when you don't install from sources? I installed it  as `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tensorflow-model-server`

Comment: I installed tensorflow serving using your instructions on Ubuntu 16.04.
Then, I ran: `sudo find / | grep tensorflow-model-server`. One of the result was: `/var/cache/apt/archives/tensorflow-model-server_1.7.0_all.deb` meaning that it installed tensorflow serving version 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

If one installs Tensor flow serving using

1. `apt-get`, we can find the installed version by using `apt list --installed`
2. For `pip` installation use `pip freeze`
3. For `conda` installation use `conda list`